# How to signout from onedrive in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: lumia, onedrive, 8.1

I have multiple one drive account . Earlier in windows phone 8 I was able to do a signout and login into another account , but now I am not finding that option . How can I do it in windows phone 8.1 ? I download preview version of windows 8.1

Comment: I heard that some things are more integrated in 8.1.In this case is possible you will need a 3rd party app to login with another account or perhaps use the browser. Don't know for sure. Couldn't find the sign out too.

Answer (score 3):

The latest [OneDrive app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/onedrive/9wzdncrfj1p3) for Windows phone 8.1 allows using multiple accounts.

1. Click on the hamburger icon.
   [image]
2. Press Add account button.
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot sign out of the OneDrive app. If you want to sign in with a different account, you must do it on the website. As an alternative to the app, you can pin the website to your Start screen and use that for other logins.

Answer (score 2):

You can logout from onedrive from your lumia phone. first set up a pin from your setting then close your onedrive and again open it and enter wrong pin for 5 times then it will automatically will logout from your account.

Answer (score 1):

As Drowin mentioned, there is no way to logout of OneDrive app starting Windows Phone 8.1. Read more about [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/sdpersonalization-sdaccess/how-can-i-log-out-from-onedrive-on-windows-phone/f87dd715-06a2-404c-a073-67dd3c55c82d).

As a workaround, you can share all your folders on your other account with the account that is associated with WP. With that you should be able to view all your files here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can someone care to explain why was the answer downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not upgrade to Windows Phone 8.1 then the OneDrive app for Windows Phone 8 works well. I have two Nokia 928s and the OneDrive app on the WP 8 works perfect...you can log out and into seperate onedrive accounts. In Windows Phone 8.1...your screwed.